# Ninject intercept throwing error. Dynamic proxy

Tags: ninject, interceptor

I have a class which I use to bootstrap.
as part of the object creation I use by convention to bind to interfaces.

All works OK until I try to add an interceptor.

```
public class ContainerBootstrapper : IDisposable
    {
        StandardKernel _c;

        public ContainerBootstrapper()
        {
            _c =new StandardKernel();

            _c.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("Facade*.*").SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterfaces()); 
            _c.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("Object*.*").SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterfaces());
            _c.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("Logger*.*").SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterfaces());

//even using the built in ActionInterceptor like this:

_c.Intercept(c => true)
            .With(new ActionInterceptor(invocation =>
                    Console.Write(invocation.Request.Method.Name)));
```

When this line is hit, I get an error - Error loading Ninject component IAdviceFactory
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Suggestions:
  1) If you have created a custom subclass for KernelBase, ensure that you have properly
     implemented the AddComponents() method.
  2) Ensure that you have not removed the component from the container via a call to RemoveAll().
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.

I have at the top:

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Injection.Dynamic;
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Infrastructure.Language;
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception;
```

and used NuGet for packages. Tried both Dynamic Proxies and LinFu. Both gave same error.

Anyone have any ideas to try?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that even though I had a reference to the project doing the bootstrapping and I thought all my dlls for ninject where being copied over automatically this was not the case. After moving them manually it worked.